# AES Test Vectors with plaintext of arbitrary length

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, pkcs#7

Are there any AES test vectors for encrypting/decrypting plaintexts of arbitrary lengths?

All I could find was test vectors for plaintexts which lengths were multiples of 16 bytes...

I need it to validate my internal padding function (PKCS#7) in an AES implementation

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there are most likely no specific AES test vectors with other length than the AES blocklength ...

but since you want to test a PKCS7 implementation, what do you want with AES test vectors anyways?

AES handles blocks ... 128 bit at a time ... when you have a working AES implemtation, you are safe to assume that DEC(ENC(DATA,K),K) = DATA ...

so all you need to test is if your padding function produces the same output as a PKCS7 reference implementation whithout any cipher behind it ... AES has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: You're right! Thanks.


I have to add that I found test vector for AES-CTR mode that operate on plaintexts that are 36 bytes long.
You can find them here : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3686